# This auto render border script wont work with CLI but works fine in the GUI

Tags: python, rendering, cycles-render-engine, scripting, render-border

This **registered** script works fine inside the GUI when I open the blend file, It refuses to work in CLI mode. I can see that the script runs because it prints the values at the end of the script. Its as if taking the coordinates from the object before the animation kicks in. If I save at frame 20 and render frame 50 the border will be where frame 20 is(I did not save the border in the blend). But the cube is in the location of frame 50.

```
from bpy_extras.object_utils import world_to_camera_view
import bpy

border = 0.01
scene = bpy.data.scenes["Scene"]
verts = bpy.data.objects["Cube.002"].data.vertices

accuracy = int(len(verts) / 5000)

if accuracy < 1:
    accuracy = 1
x = []
y = []

for v in range(0, len(verts), accuracy):
    v2 = bpy.data.objects["Cube.002"].matrix_world @ verts[v].co
    x.append(world_to_camera_view(scene, bpy.data.objects["Camera"], v2).x)
    y.append(world_to_camera_view(scene, bpy.data.objects["Camera"], v2).y)

bpy.context.scene.render.border_max_x = max(x) + border
bpy.context.scene.render.border_min_x = min(x) - border
bpy.context.scene.render.border_max_y = max(y) + border
bpy.context.scene.render.border_min_y = min(y) - border

print(min(y), max(y), min(x), max(x))
```

Comment: Could be due to argument order https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#argument-order. What is your command line?

Comment: .\blender.exe -b border_render.blend -s 2 -e 2 -a

Comment: Maybe using --python-expr <expression> so that you can give the starting frame to the script (via a function which will include your current code) and set the frame as current in it.

Comment: It's an order of things. If a text block `foo.py` is registered they are run first. and just like an addon. imported and  the  `register` method called.   SImilarly to what is suggested by lemon, use `--python-text foo.py` to run the text block after setting frame.

Comment: So there is no way to delay it at all? Well without modifying the cli. The problem is I want it to work out of the box GUI and CLI for the render farm and for users. Sure I can tell the render farm to run it but that is adding unnecessary complexity to the farm

Comment: Actually after trying --python-text border.py it still doesn't seem to work